# Conditional expectation on Bi variate probability distribution

Tags: probability

Two balls are drawn simultaneously from an urn containing 2$0$ balls numbered $1,2,3...20$. let $X$ be the number on one of the drawn ball and $Y$ be the number on the other. Find $E(XY)$.

I try to solve using $E(XY)=E\{YE(X|Y)\}$, but I cant make progress? Ant help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This being 2015, I would be tempted to use the brute-force approach with a spreadsheet. At the very least this will allow you to check any analytical answer you might get.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows:

$$
E(XY) = \sum_{i=1}^{20} E(XY|Y=i)P(Y=i) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}iE(X|Y=i)P(Y=i)
$$
For calculating $E(X|Y=i)$, we know that if $Y=i$, then $X$ cannot be equal to $i$ and is uniformly distributed on others. Therefore,

$$
E(X|Y=i) = \frac{1+2+\dots +20 - i}{19} = \frac{210-i}{19}
$$
Therefore,

$$
E(XY) = \sum_{i=1}^{20}i\frac{210-i}{19}P(Y=i) = \frac{210}{19}E(Y)-\frac{1}{19}E(Y^2)
$$

$Y$ is uniformly distributed over $1,\dots,20$.